# how to check the mail sending is successful in MailSendingMessageHandler

Tags: spring-integration

I want to send mail from my application by using spring integration. I used MailSendingMessageHandler to send email which uses smtp protocol.

```
@Bean
    public JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender() {
        final JavaMailSenderImpl mailSenderImpl = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
        mailSenderImpl.setHost(env.getProperty("integration.mail.host"));
        mailSenderImpl.setPort(Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty("integration.mail.port")));
        mailSenderImpl.setUsername(env.getProperty("integration.mail.username"));
        mailSenderImpl.setPassword(env.getProperty("integration.mail.password"));
        mailSenderImpl.setJavaMailProperties(additionalMailProperties());
        mailSenderImpl.setProtocol(env.getProperty("integration.mail.protocol"));
        return mailSenderImpl;
    }

    /**
     * Mail sending message handler.
     *
     * @return the mail sending message handler
     */
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "sendEmailRequestChannel")
    @Bean
    public MailSendingMessageHandler mailSendingMessageHandler() {
        final MailSendingMessageHandler handler = new MailSendingMessageHandler(mailSender);
        handler.setLoggingEnabled(true);
        return handler;
    }
```

but i am not getting any response. i need to know whether the email has send successfully. i think MailSendingMessageHandler is an adapter. is there any gateway implementation , so that i'll geta mail sending status as a reply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; if no exception was thrown, then the send was successful.

A failure will cause an exception to be thrown.